# Could the prepositional phrase be replaced by a absolute/non-finite construction acting as a supplement?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, non-restrictive, nonfinite-clause-complementation

> When everyone was seated, he suggested going around the table, ***with each guest telling the others about their missing children.***

Source:- https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/07/06/five-hostages

> When everyone was seated, he suggested going around the table, ***each guest telling the others about their missing children.***

Comment: Yes; I'd say that the adjunct in your first example can be replaced with the supplement in your second example. It would be an absolute construction by virtue of having a subject and no syntactic link to the main clause.

Comment: I agree that they're equivalent, but the first seems more idiomatic to me.

Comment: I don't know if it's a rule, but to me the preposition version implies that he instructed each guest to tell, while the absolute version implies that the guest actions were spontaneous or automatic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute phrase with preposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379135/absolute-phrase-with-preposition) (though 'absolute clause' is the modern analysis).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, the linked question clarified my doubts

Comment: Absolute constructions are rare in speech but more common in formal writing ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction)), so in speech a preposition would be more usual.